# JNI: What signature to use when returning a user defined java class?

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface, signature

Based on this [file](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jni/spec/types.html#wp276) a fully-qualified-class signature is `Lfully-defined-class`.
ex. `String` --> `Ljava/lang/string`

How about user defined class? are they also considered fully-defined-class?
For example i created a class `Container`. Can i use `"LContainer"` as signature? I know my other code works when i use simple String for example but when i replace it with my own userdefined class, for some reason i might be missing, it doesn't work anymore.

`getClass` is a static method that returns a `Container` type value. Is my signature correct?   `()LContainer`

```
jmethodID mid = env->GetStaticMethodID(clazz, "getClass", "()LContainer")
```

Please let me know what you think. Thanks in advance

Comment: You cease guessing and use the output of `javap -s`. It is never wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Oracle Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javap.html) and [OpenJDK](http://openjdk.java.net/tools/sctools.html) provide the `javap` tool that helps with JNI signatures.

For example, to find the signature of the `probablePrime` method in the `BigInteger` class:

```
javap -s java.math.BigInteger | grep -A 2 "probablePrime"

public static java.math.BigInteger probablePrime(int, java.util.Random);
   descriptor: (ILjava/util/Random;)Ljava/math/BigInteger;
```

—just as with `java`, provide the classpath to your compiled .class file.

While this doesn't get you the signature for a class directly, surely there is some method or field that references the class so can find the class descriptor somewhere.

Comment: Thanks, This helped a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `Container` is in package `com.contosso`, you need `"()Lcom/contosso/Container;"`

I don't know how you would handle the case where `Container` is in the default package.  The obvious workround is to move it into a package :-)

Thanks to [user2543253](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2543253/user2543253) for pointing out the missing semi-colon in the spec

Comment: What if Container is not in any package? I thought LContainer would work since when i tested returning an integer, the format ()I worked for me. Unfortunately LContainer doesn't work.

Comment: You're missing the `;` at the end (as does the OP).

Comment: Martin Bonner, In my case, my .java file is in the same directory as the C++ which is my current working directory. You can set the CLASSPATH  "." then using your JavaVMOption structure, access its member options to assign the class path. Now all that FindClass needs to know is the class name

Comment: user254353 sorry about the OP its a typo. There is a semicolon and it still had the issue.

Comment: The semicolon *is* part of the argument. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/types.html#type_signatures

Comment: D'oh!  Yes, I see what you mean.